# Odd-degree hyperellptic curve ramified at infinity

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ be the projective curve with the affine model given by the equation $Y^2=F(X)$, where $F$ is a polynomial in $x$ with degree $d$ over a field $k$ with characteristic not equal to 2. When $d$ is odd, why is $C$ ramified at the point at infinity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hurwitz's formula says
$$   2g(C)-2=2\cdot (2g(\mathbb P^1)-2)+ \mid Ram\mid   $$
Hence the number $ \mid Ram\mid $ of ramification points is even and since there are only $d$ in the affine part, there must be one at infinity too.